# Match a keyword from a list data type in Cypher

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher, match

I ran a cypher query to delete all duplicate relationship with same name from my graph. A relationship has properties(name, confidence, time). I kept the relationship with highest confidence value and collected all time values, using following query:

```
MATCH (e0:Entity)-[r:REL]-(e1:Entity)
WITH e0, r.name AS relation, COLLECT(r) AS rels, COLLECT(r.confidence)AS relConf, MAX(r.confidence) AS maxConfidence, COLLECT(r.time) AS relTime, e1 WHERE SIZE(rels) > 1
SET (rels[0]).confidence = maxConfidence, (rels[0]).time = relTime 
FOREACH (rel in tail(rels) | DELETE rel)
RETURN rels, relation, relConf, maxConfidence, relTime
```

Old Data:

```
name,confidence,time
likes, 0.87, 20111201010900
likes, 0.97, 20111201010600
```

New data:

```
name,confidence,time
likes, 0.97, [20111201010900,20111201010600]
```

Could anyone please suggest a match query to find relationships containing year 2011 in new "time" property?? (I converted time using toInt while loading from a csv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new data structure is definitely not easy to make such searches, but it is possible on medium graphs :

```
MATCH (n:Entity)-[r:REL]->(x)
WHERE ANY(
          t IN extract(x IN r.time | toString(x)) 
          WHERE t STARTS WITH "2011"
         )
RETURN r
```

Comment: It worked, thanks you...! Couldn't be there one regular expression, to find such relations, as in future i would like to find all relationship in a given month 12 or date 20th or different combinations, etc. I also loaded "time" property as string and tried few regular expression too, but it did not work on a list.

Comment: Filtering on relationship properties is not efficient and even less efficient when this property is an array. I would suggest you group your relationship types by month or days, for eg `()-[:201112]->()` or `()-[:20111201]->()` which would already be a great improvement in terms of performance

Comment: And please accept the answer if it works, thanks ! :-)

Comment: So you are saying for better performance, I should label my relation type with date, instead of setting it as relation property. I am loading data from csv, it there any way i can define label from the date column of my csv file in "load csv" query?

Comment: No you can't do it from LOAD CSV unfortunately. The kind of model to use depends highly on the type of queries you want to do. Date Aware relationships are one way, Intermediate nodes representing events and a timetree are another way https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree . There is no out of the box solution, you need to test and keep the one that suits your needs.